# Как удалить фичи с нулевыми весами из feature_importances_?

Tags: python

Измерили вес фичей в модели обучения, получился массив значений clf.feature_importances_
Как удалить фичи с нулевым весом из тренировочной выборки?

````
x = df_prepared.drop(['price_category'], axis=1)
y = df_prepared['price_category']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42
)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)```
````